# If I'm using Google Oauth, is there an easy way to see a list of users who have authenticated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

If I'm using Google Oauth, is there an easy way to see a list of users who have authenticated in GCP? I've created an addon for the Google Workspace Addon store.

Thanks!

Comment: Your addon will need to track who authenticates via your addon.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apps Script appsscript.json manifest file should have the scope:

```
 . . . ./auth/userinfo.email
```

That scope should also be listed in your Marketplace SDK App Configuration OAuth scopes.  Any time that your add-on code runs, it can get the account email of the account that installed the add-on.

The reserved function name `onInstall()` is triggered by the install event.  It only runs when the add-on is installed.  So you can get the users email address then in order to avoid having that line of code run at other times.

```
function onInstall() {
try{
  var effectiveUsr;
  
  effectiveUsr = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();//getActiveUser does NOT work in on Install
  
  onOpen();
  //Dont automatically open the side bar on installation - That is against the guidelines
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
}
```

After the code gets the email of the user that installed the add-on, you could do various things to maintain a list of users who installed your add-on.  You could store the user email in Properties Service so that it's available later.  Then at some point you could save the user email to your records in your account.  Whatever you do with personal data needs to be explained in the Privacy Policy.

Depending upon the scopes (permissions) that your add-on asks for, will dictate how you get the users email.